# How can I run a Python GTK GUI and a chat at the same time?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, gtk, glade

Can someone help me with Python GTK + sockets? I'm trying to make a chat, so I'm running this to receive messages from other users:

```py
def socket_recv(socket, buffer):
    while True:
        try:
            message = socket.recv(1024).decode()
            end_iter = buffer.get_end_iter()
            buffer.insert(end_iter, message + "\n")
            while Gtk.events_pending():
                Gtk.main_iteration()
        except:
            print("Você foi desconectado do servidor")
            socket.close()
            break
```

and in my main, I am trying to run this event:

```py
def onConnect(self, widget):
        self.nickname = self.nickname_entry.get_text().strip()
        self.adress = self.adress_entry.get_text().strip()

        if self.nickname == "" or self.adress == "": 
            self.error_message.show()
            return

        HOST, PORT = self.adress.split(':')
        PORT = int(PORT)
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.connect((HOST, PORT))

        self.sock.send(str.encode(self.nickname))
        
        self.builder.add_from_file("interface.glade")  
        self.builder.connect_signals(self)

        self.chat_text.set_editable(False)
        self.chat_text.set_wrap_mode(3)
        self.chat_buffer = self.chat_text.get_buffer()
        self.chat_buffer.set_text("Início do chat\n")
        self.end_iter = self.chat_buffer.get_end_iter()

        self.chatWindow.show()

        while Gtk.events_pending():
                Gtk.main_iteration()

        thread = threading.Thread(target=socket_recv(self.sock, self.chat_buffer))
        thread.start()
```

I get the adress and nickname of the user in the starting window of the GUI, and then try to connect to the server after they click on the button "Connect", then the chat window appear. Although I can connect to the server, when I try to run my chat GUI with the socket_recv,  the GUI becomes completely nonfunctional (buttons cant be pressed, etc.) and I have to force quit to close the application.
I'm pretty new to Python, GTK and threading, and would appreciate any help

Comment: Fixed, I just changed 
```threading.Thread(target=socket_recv(self.sock, self.chat_buffer))```
to
```thread = threading.Thread(target=socket_recv, args=(self.sock, self.chat_buffer))```

Comment: Please post the answer as an answer, not a comment. See [answer] for more information on answering questions.

Comment: Will do, sorry!

Comment: No problem. Just remember to do it in the future :-)!

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved guys, I just changed

`threading.Thread(target=socket_recv(self.sock, self.chat_buffer))`

to

`thread = threading.Thread(target=socket_recv, args=(self.sock, self.chat_buffer))`

Sorry for any inconvenience